# find x-axis values according to y-axis values in python

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

I have a plot of normalised distance (range 0-1) on x-axis, and an index values on the y-axis. The index values sum up to 100%. I want to find the top accumulated 10%, i.e. the peak in the curve, and then get it's boundaries on the x-axis.

See the figure for a graphic explanation of what I want to find.

numpy, pandas, scipy, are all works for me.

Ideally, I would be able to colour the line where the top-10% in one colour, than top-20% in different colour.

Thanks,

ALCZ

[Here is a picture of what I'm looking for](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A7USA.png)